# is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerforme

Tags: java

MainDemo is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerforme (ActionEvent) in ActionListener

I don't know why this error occurs whenever I compile , although I override the method (ActionPerformed) , so what is the solution?

```
private void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)throws ClassNotFoundException,   IOException {  
    user.importEvent(jTextField1.getText());

  }
```

Comment: I see no MainDemo in your code, so what are we supposed to think about it ?

Comment: Is it `actionPerforme` or `ActionPerformed`?

Comment: Java's case sensitive, it should actionPerformed, it also can't be private

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not complete, but if you mean the `actionPerformed` of the `ActionListener` interface (swing), you didn't override it.

Overriding a method means to define/redefine a method with the same signature of that method in the corresponding interface or super class. Also the names of the method must be the same case. (Rule of case-sensitivity in java)

So if you want to override the `actionListener(ActionEvent e)`, your method should look like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    ...
}
```

Another rule in overriding is that you cannot reduce the access modifier of a method. So if a method's original access modifier is `protected` you can only increase the access to something like `public`. Here the original access modifier is `public`, so you can only define it with `public`, and `private` is not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Method names are case-sensitive in Java. The method you're trying to override is `actionPerformed`, not `ActionPerformed`.

Also, in order to keep the signature consistent with the interface it needs to be `public` and it can't throw a checked exception.